# Ionic2 dynamic navigation

Tags: dynamic, angular, menu, navigation, ionic2

I'm building an app where the data comes from the server. The menu is dynamic, and the server can send different menus depending on the user profile. I will never know what will be the component/page, that the menu item will have, I just need to have that component/page available.

The main problem is that I need to do a lot of components/pages imports and I do not want to that in every component/page.

I created a service, where all the imports are made and a method exists to return the correct component, so the navController could navigate.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//Import navigation pages
import { NotificationsPage } from "./../pages/notifications/notifications";
import { ClubPage } from "./../pages/club/club";
import { ActivitiesPage } from "./../pages/activities/activities";
import { NewsPage } from "./../pages/news/news";
import { CalendarPage } from "./../pages/calendar/calendar";
import { NewsletterPage } from "./../pages/newsletter/newsletter";
import { SettingsPage } from "./../pages/settings/settings";
import { FavoritesPage } from "./../pages/favorites/favorites";
import { SubmenuPage } from "./../pages/submenu/submenu";
import { ContentDetailsPage } from "./../pages/contentdetails/contentdetails";

@Injectable()
export class ViewNavigatorService
{
      public NOTIFICATIONS:string = "notifications";
      public CLUB:string = "club";
      public ACTIVITIES:string = "activities";
      public NEWS:string = "news";
      public CALENDAR:string = "calendar";
      public NEWSLETTER:string = "newsletter";
      public SETTINGS:string = "settings";
      public FAVORITS:string = "favorits";

      public SUBMENU:string = "submenu";
      public CONTENT_DETAILS:string = "content-details";

      public GetComponent(page:string, data?:any):any
      {
            let Component = null;

            switch (page) 
            {
                  case this.NOTIFICATIONS:      Component = NotificationsPage;     break;
                  case this.CLUB:               Component = ClubPage;              break;
                  case this.ACTIVITIES:         Component = ActivitiesPage;        break;
                  case this.NEWS:               Component = NewsPage;              break;
                  case this.CALENDAR:           Component = CalendarPage;          break;
                  case this.NEWSLETTER:         Component = NewsletterPage;        break;
                  case this.SETTINGS:           Component = SettingsPage;          break;
                  case this.FAVORITS:           Component = FavoritesPage;         break;
                  case this.SUBMENU:            Component = SubmenuPage;           break;
                  case this.CONTENT_DETAILS:    Component = ContentDetailsPage;    break;

                  default:                      Component = null;                  break;
            }

            return Component;
      }
}
```

If I only inject the service in a parent page it works, but if I also inject the service in a child page, I get this error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for SubmenuPage: (NavController, NavParams, PopoverController, AlertController, ModalController, ?).

The ? should be the "ViewNavigatorService".

Why this error happens?

Is there a better way to do this?  What are you using when your app uses dynamic navigation?